# How to create a new python DataFrame with multiple columns of differing row lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm organizing a new dataframe in order to easily insert data into a Bokeh visualization code snippet. I think my problem is due to differing row lengths, but I am not sure.

Below, I organized the dataset in alphabetical order, by country name, and created an alphabetical list of the individual countries. [new_data.tail()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ni3.png) Although Zimbabwe is listed last, there are 80336 rows, hence the sorting.

```
    df_ind_data = pd.DataFrame(ind_data)
    new_data = df_ind_data.sort_values(by=['country'])
    new_data = new_data.reset_index(drop=True)
    country_list = list(ind_data['country'])
    new_country_set = sorted(set(country_list))
```

My goal is create a new DataFrame, with 76 cols (country names), with the specific **'trust'** data in the rows underneath each country column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for country in new_country_set:
    pink = new_data.loc[(new_data['country'] == country)]
    df[country] = pink.trust
```

[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo0Vz.png)

As you can see, the data does not get included for the rest of the columns after the first. I believe this is due to the fact that the number of rows of 'trust' data for each country varies. While the first column has 1000 rows, there are some with as many as 2500 data points, and as little as 500.

I have attempted a few different methods to specify the number of rows in 'df', but to no avail.

**The visualization code snippet I have utilizes this same exact data structure for the template data, so that it why I'm attempting to put it in a dataframe.** Plus, I can't do it, so I want to know how to do it.

Yes, I can put it in a dictionary, but I want to put it in a dataframe.

Comment: What advantage will shoehorning irregular data into a regular data structure offer?

Comment: I need this specific structure in order to create a particular visualization, of which the code is pulled from Bokeh. If I use a different structure, I'll just end up having to edit the Bokeh code and manage the errors encountered in that process. 

Since the code snippet is even more advanced, there are a lot of unknowns if I undertake that route.

Also, for a seemingly easy question to clarify, it doesn't seem as if there is much in the way of an easy answer. Seems like a good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **combine_first** when you add a new column so that the dataframe index gets extended. Instead of

```
df[country] = pink.trust
```

you should use

```
df = pink.trust.combine_first(df)
```

which ensures that your index is always union of all added columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case `pd.pivot(columns = 'var', values = 'val')` , will work for you, especially when you already have dataframe. This function will transfer values from particular column into column names. You could see the documentation for additional info. I hope that helps.